# C# Reverse() function not working properly

Tags: c#, built-in

I'm really confused why the reverse function isn't working properly..

I currently have

```
List<string> decimalVector = new List<string>();
string tempString = "10"
//For Vector Representation

for (int i = 0; i < tempString.Length; i++)
{
    //As long as we aren't at the last digit...
    if (i != (tempString.Length-1))
    {
        decimalVector.Add(tempString[i].ToString() + ",");
    }
    else
    {
        decimalVector.Add(tempString[i].ToString());
    }
}

Console.Write("Decimal: " + decimalOutput);
Console.Write(" Vector Representation: [");
decimalVector.Reverse();
for (int i = 0; i < decimalVector.Count; i++) 
{
   Console.Write(decimalVector[i]); 
}
Console.Write("]");
```

For some reason instead of the code outputting **[0,1]** as it should - since that is the reverse of what is currently in the `decimalVector` (**[1,0]**) ..It prints out **[01,]** I am so confused. Why is it randomly moving my comma out of place? Am I doing something really stupid and not seeing it?

Comment: This is because you are putting a coma in the value in the list, rather than printing that out when you output to the console.

Comment: Seems everyone has similar problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542032/printing-reversed-array-list-c-sharp

Comment: Actually it was a logical mistake on my part. The Reverse function actually works correctly. What I was doing was assuming that the Reverse() function reverses the actual characters when all it does is reverse the elements - in which the concerning element was actually concatenated into the same one. So it was coincidence that it looked correct in forward form. Thanks for all your help everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reversing the order of the elements, not the order of the characters. It's `1,` followed by `0`. When reversed it's `0` followed by `1,`. When you print that, you get `01,`.

You should not include the separating `,` as part of the list elements, but rather only add it when printing.

Btw there is the `string.Join` method, which solves your problem elegantly:

```
string.join(",", tempString.Select(c => c.ToString()).Reverse())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        foreach (string s in decimalVector.Reverse()) 
        {
           Console.Write(s); 
        }
```